# Bibliography on Templates

Tags: bibliographies, templates

I'm using a latex template and typing my bibliography where it says "insert bibliography entry...", however, there are some parts missing when i compile the document. Specifically, anything but books aren't shown with the date, editor, nor pages, even when i'm typing that information! How can i fix this?

I'm using

```
\bibliographystyle{plaindin_esp}
\bibliography{BibliMSc}
```

and when i type something like this:

```
@article{Example1,   
author = {Example2},
title = {Example3},
journaltitle = {Example4},
date = {2014},}
```

I get this:

[image: Journal title and date doesn't appear. How can i fix this?]

Journal title and date doesn't appear. How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you provide more information in the form of a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl))?  Not everyone creates `.tex` files in the same way, and I don't quite understand what you are doing.

Comment: @jon I hope my edit helps me to be clear

Comment: @Tomas Not quite. Have you clicked the first link jon has provided? There's more information on how to make a MWE. As well, where does `plaindin_esp.bst` file come from? I don't seem to have it in TeXlive.

Comment: A guess: this is a _BibTeX_ style file, so you should be writing `journal` instead of `journaltitle`.  The latter is part of the `biblatex` style instead.  If this does not solve it please provide us with a link to the source of `plaindin_esp.bst`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields `journaltitle` and `date` are not supported by standard `bibtex` styles (they are supported by `biblatex`). To use `bibtex` you have to replace `journaltitle` by `journal`  and `date` by `year`.